# Pandas column - converting string into specific date format

Tags: python, pandas

One of the columns in my pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
14.3.2019
15.3.2019
16.3.2019
```

So this is European/German date that I have to convert to USA format:

```
2019-3-14
2019-3-15
2019-3-16
```

What is the fastest way to do it, possibly inplace, if I have a large dataset?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: add `.dt`: `pd.to_datetime(...).dt.strftime`? But, as suggested by @anky_91, don't use string, just use `datetime` format, i.e., use `pd.to_datetime` only.

Comment: @anky-91 It worked! Put it in answer please.

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried your solution with .dt and it also worked. Also it seems much faster. How so?

Comment: @Harvey much faster than what? The difference between my suggestion and anky's is that I pass the format so pandas doesn't need to *guess*. If you have consistent format, then that's the way to go.

Comment: @QuangHoang faster than anky-91 answer. Thank you for explanation, it makes perfect sense. Put it in answer so I can accept it. I like you answer better since it gives idea for different format transformation, and also it's faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer given by both commenters, posting here faster solution from `@QuangHoang`.

Casting `string` column in `date` type in desired format:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```